Looking for correct keyword for a "time series" however each random variable has different probability distribution.
precisely I am looking for the following. Given a set of random variables $X_0,X_i,...X_n$. Each RV has its own probability distribution. Additionally, RV with larger index is dependent on the RV with smaller index.
I can sample the series however many times to estimate necessary parameters.
I want investigate properties such as bounding the probability that the sum of a subset of RVs fall into a range etc...
After some research, I don't like Chebyshev's in this case, because it does not capture the characteristics in this case. Looking for a tighter bound. Much appreciate any helps!

The keywords you are interested include stochastic process and possibly martingale.
If you can bound the differences between successive variables, then the Azuma's inequality might be helpful. The inequality has some useful generalizations e.g. Warnke 2015 has a version where you have a bound on typical differences and allow larger differences that are rare.

Thank you very much Martin. I now understand my problem fits in stochastic process. However, unfortunately my series does not comply martingale property. Let me brief my use case, because it adds clarity.
Consider a computer program which can be divided into 10 sub-jobs. All jobs run in-order, one-by-one, back-to-back. The execution time for each sub-job is a RV, $X_i$.
It's possible that, say, $X_5,X_6$ are in fact constant and not equal. This violate the martingale property, if I am not mistaken.

Assuming the first 5 subjobs have finished, can I bound the probability of the sum of the remainder ( $\sum_{I=6}^{10} X_i$)? I can treat the sum as a RV and use Chebyshev's, but it will not take consideration of the first 5 subjobs which could greatly impact the execution time of the later five. I feel I need some thing like “conditional Chebyshev’s”
Thank you for your input

It might make more sense to layout all the information you have and ask a new question. There's a lot of research in "scheduling" which might be directly relevant.  Note that as stated, there are no bounds. Nothing is stopping  $X_{10}$ from being arbitrarily large. Even Chebyshev may not apply if the mean or variance of any of the distributions is undefined. If there are extra assumptions you can make, state them all clearly in a new question.
